# what is the url for wp core install --url for kubernetes?

Tags: wordpress, minikube, wp-cli

In kubernetes, I have a wordpress container and a wp-cli `Job`.

To create the WordPress tables in the database using the URL, title, and default admin user details, I am running this command in the wp-cli Job:

```
wp core install --url=http://localhost:8087 --title=title --admin_user=user --admin_password=pass --admin_email=someone@email.com --skip-email
```

The `--url` parameter prevents Minikube from serving the wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the ip address of your service there in place of "localhost".
When i say service, I'm talking about the service that exposes your deployment/pods (its another kubernetes object you got to create).

You can pass the IP address  using an environment variable . When creating a service, the pods that are started inherit extra environment variables that kubernetes places in them, through which you can access the ip address, the port, both etc... check documentation.

The second option is to place there the name of your service (still talking about the kubernetes object you created to expose your deployment). It will be resolved to the IP address in fine by the DNS of the cluster (CoreDNS as of today is started along with minikube).

Those two options are in the documentation in the same section called discovering services.

I had trouble to understand that things like: service-name.name-space.svc.cluster.default are like any url (like subsubdomain.subdomain.stackoverflow.com) but being resolved within the cluster.